# @RequestParam from @RequestMapping Java

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc

I have a method as below

```
@RequestMapping("/someUrl")
public void setup(@RequstParam("name") String name, @RequstParam("desc") String desc) {
    ....
}
```

Can i get a list of the @RequestParam in the method when calling the method from javascript without losing the original function of the method?

In response to the comments,
I want to get a list of the parameters needed in the url to call that method. e.g. i want to call some method that returns a javascript array/object with "name" and "desc" in it (e.g. ["name","desc"].

Comment: Do you want to pass two or more parameter values within the url?

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do in more detail.

Comment: So you want to make an ajax call that tells you what parameters must be passed to the setup method?  In other words there would be another controller method that gives you the `RequestParam` information about `setup`?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i want